# Figure spanning full width of page in two-column article

Tags: latex

In a IEEEtran latex template, I am trying to put a figure spanning full width of the page.
I am doing,

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.25pt}
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=6.2in]{Figure7}}
\caption{Figure}
\label{f7}
\end{figure*}
```

This places the image on a new page at the end of the article. How do I place it where it should be?
Thanks

Comment: so... what was the solution?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For starters I might try to put the `figure*` block further up in the document, just to check that LaTeX isn't placing it there for a logical reason.

If that doesn't work, I would remove all extraneous commands in the figure* block to be sure they aren't causing problems.

Finally I might try using a figure that doesn't need resizing, or use `[width=0.9\linewidth]` just to check; sometimes figures that are "too big" can get bumped to the end of the document.

Edit: You may also try using (temporarily) a different template. For example I know that `revtex4-1` has a `figure*` environment that behaves the way to want, to check if `ieeetran` is the problem or perhaps if that is part of their style.

Answer (score 7):

the problem is the [h].
get rid of that, it'll work.

Comment: Worked for me (with the [h] I indeed get it on some page by itself at the end, without it comes more or less where it should be), and I don't think the idea of stackoverflow is just to answer questions for the OP.

Comment: By removing the [h], my figure actually jumped one page up. Also, I agree with Claude that Stack is also useful for any passers-by like me.